# Joining multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join, multiple-tables

I am trying to join multiple tables in MySQL, here is the query:

```
SELECT p.post_title
     , p.post_content
     , p.guid
     , i.guid
     , m.meta_value
  FROM twypl_posts p
  JOIN twypl_posts i 
    ON i.ID = p.post_parent 
  JOIN twypl_postmeta m 
    ON p.ID = m.post_id
 WHERE p.post_status = "publish" 
   AND p.post_type   = "product"
   AND i.post_type   = "attachment"
   AND m.meta_key IN ("_product_attributes", "_sku", "_price")
```

So basically I have 2 tables, `twypl_posts` and `twypl_postmeta`, but I want to join 3 tables, 2 `twypl_posts` (one with only "product" `post_type` and one with only "attachment" `post_type`) and a `twypl_postmeta` table. 
They are all connected via a foreign key `ID` (`twypl_posts`), `post_parent` AND `post_id` respectively. `twypl_posts` has a `post_parent` for "attachment" `post_types` which link to the parent product (`twypl_posts` with `post_type` "product").

When I run the above query it doesn't return any results (no query errors).

My SQL has gotten a little rusty after using frameworks that have sophisticated DRM. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just start debugging, remove the WHERE do you get anything?

Comment: @Mihai Yes tried that, removing the WHERE returns results. As soon as I add the where clause I get no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a mistake there : `INNER JOIN twypl_posts i ON p.post_parent = i.ID`
It should be `INNER JOIN twypl_posts i ON p.ID = i.post_parent`
Since **i** is the attachment